# How can we set synonyms in Apache Solr like this way?

Tags: solr

I am using synonyms file in Apache Solr for mapping synonyms based on query.

Now I want to setup filters based on query

If somebody types

```
Ex: I want a teen model for my photoshoot
```

Then it should set filter in **age** field like **age:[13 TO 19]** automatically.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: I have not tried anything. I don't know how to do this using synonyms.